# Strange behaviour of UItextView inside Tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a `UItextView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. When I select some text inside the `textview`, I have a strange animation: the `cell` or the `textview` (I don't know wich `scrollview` is really moving, may be both) start scrolling up and down maybe because both `scrollviews` (`Tableviewcontroller's` `scrollview` or `UItextView's` `scroll view` ) want to focus the selected text for their own in different ways. I've tried anything but this bad animation is still here.

The `Tableviewcontroller` and the `textfield` was made with storyboard.

ps: sorry for bad english

Comment: Why are you using a text view? Should that be scrollable, or you just want a static piece of text (can you use a label)?

Comment: first u need to place your UITextview add subView to one UIView then add to UITableviewCell then it will work .... and also let me know if u still have any issues

Comment: I have putted the textview in a view and then placed in the cntent view of a tableview cell. It doesnt work!

Comment: I think you need to handle the both states. Like when textfield is get selected, in its delegate textViewBeginEditing, set textView.scrollEnabled = FALSE. 

You need to maintain the scrollEnabled state, while editing and when editing done (for view only).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

when the textView is focused.

Comment: i need the scroll of tableview because when keyboard appears i have to move automatically the cell over the keyboard. i can't disable the scroll.

Comment: @Andorath Do it after you move the cell.

Answer (score 0):

- if you want to show a static text just use the uilabel, which is enough.
- but if you want to show and let the user edit the textview, you may allow to edit it while the tableview is in edit mode.